# "UnsupportedOperationException: Collision adding composited set with no SetMutator set" related to Apache collection4's CompositeMap

Tags: java, spring5, apache-commons-collection

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Collision adding composited set with no SetMutator set
```

is thrown when Spring reads the below configuration. According to the [documentation of API CompositeMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CompositeMap.html), it looks like setMutator is to be set somewhere, but not sure how. Besides, this didn't seem to be problem when Java8 & Spring 3 were used, the exception is thrown when I tried to upgrade Java to 11 and Spring to 5.

```
<bean>
  <bean id="EntityToRepository" class="org.apache.commons.collections4.map.CompositeMap">
  <constructor-arg ref="repo1"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="repo2"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="myMapMutator"/>
</bean>
```

full stack is like below. It looks like, even though CompositeMap is used, the issue ended up in **CompositeSet**, in which **setMutator** wasn't set. And CompositSet was triggered in Composite**Map**'s hashCode method.

```
202-0807 15:42:05,794 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
orgsprngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyzRepository' defined in class path resource [spring/repository/applicationContext-mappings.xml]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Collision adding composited set with no SetMutator set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:530) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) ~[bootstrap-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476) ~[bootstrap-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62.redhat-00011]
Caued y: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Collision adding composited set with no SetMutator set
at org.apache.commons.collections4.set.CompositeSet.addComposited(CompositeSet.java:348) ~[commons-collections4-4.0.jar:4.0]
at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.CompositeMap.entrySet(CompositeMap.java:252) ~[commons-collections4-4.0.jar:4.0]
at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.CompositeMap.hashCode(CompositeMap.java:480) ~[commons-collections4-4.0.jar:4.0]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.requiresDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:393) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.hasApplicableProcessors(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.requiresDestruction(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1846) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.registerDisposableBeanIfNecessary(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?